# How can I prevent NSTimer to call my selector function multiple times?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

I have my timer being called from the `viewDidLoad`. For the first time when the timer calls the selector, the expected result is fine. But gradually when the calls are made, the function is somehow called multiple times by the selector. I logged a `NSLog` which shows that the number of outputs are increasing. I have the code below. Hope it makes the situation clear.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    remainingTicks = 10;
    [self updateLabel];
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                       target:self
                       selector:@selector(handleTimerTick)
                       userInfo:nil
                       repeats:YES];
}

-(void)handleTimerTick
{
    remainingTicks--;
    [self updateLabel];
    if (remainingTicks <= 0) {
        [myTimer invalidate];
        myTimer = nil;
        UIButton *but = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        if (answerAt == 0) {
            [buttonA setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        }
        else if (answerAt == 1) {
            [buttonB setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        }
        else if (answerAt == 2) {
            [buttonC setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        }
        else {
            [buttonD setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        }

        [self performSelector:@selector(next:) withObject:but afterDelay:1.5 ];       
    }
}

-(void)updateLabel
{
    timerLabel.text = [[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt: remainingTicks] stringValue];
}
```

Comment: Can you post the log output please? This looks highly dodgy: `UIButton *but = [[UIButton alloc] init];`  1) the button isn't added to the view and 2) Surely it's leaking memory?

Comment: If it's using ARC, then it's not leaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewDidLoad` can be called multiple times during the lifetime of a `UIViewController` (for example if you get a memory warning and your view is not visible, the controller will release it and reload it next time it's needed). To handle this behavior properly you should either:

A) Test whether the timer exists before creating one (e.g. `if (myTimer == nil) { /* initialize the timer */ }` )

or

B) Clear the timer in your `viewDidUnload` method. (This is probably more along the lines of what you want since you most likely don't want the timer to fire events related to an invisible view).

Comment: I think it's ok to allocate resources and even timers in `viewDidLoad`. However, one must handle their release in `viewDidUnload`. In this case, in viewDidUnload one should invalidate the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the target for the NSTimer to be a weak self variable, like this:

```
__weak Object *weakSelf = self;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.f target:weakSelf selector:@selector(actionMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

That will prevent the action being called multiple times.